# Two css code is overleapping each other and can't see one of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a webpage where i can see my videos and some pictures from something. I get some free examples from w3schools for the gallery page and some video embedding code from somewhere else. These codes are working on their own but i can't figure out where is the problem exactly when i put them together.

In the style tags there is a

```
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}
```

The problem lies in here i think.

Here is my code

```js
 /* video */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#videos a').each(function() {
    var data = $(this).attr('data');
    $(this).append('<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+data+'/maxresdefault.jpg" />');
  });

  $('#videos a').click(function() {
    var data = $(this).attr('data');
    $('#loader').append('<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+data+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    $('#overlay').fadeIn(250);
  });

  $('#close').click(function() {
    $('#overlay').fadeOut(250,function() {
       $('#loader').html('');
    });
  });
});

/* VIDEÓ */
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

```css
#videos a {
   display: block;
   width: 25%;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 0 10px;
   float: left;
   cursor: pointer;
   text-decoration: none;
   outline: 0;
}

#videos a:hover {
   opacity: 0.7;
}

#videos a img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}

#overlay {
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
   position:fixed;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   left:0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 99999;
   display: none;
}

#overlay .modal {
   background: #fff;
   border-radius: 5px;
   width: 90%;
   margin: 100px auto;
   max-width: 800px;
   min-height: 100px;
   position: relative;
   padding: 30px 20px 15px;
}

#overlay .modal #close {
   position: absolute;
   top: 5px;
   right: 5px;
   cursor: pointer;
}

#overlay iframe {
   width: 100%;
}
/* VIDEÓ VÉGE */

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

              
<h1 style="text-align:center">Lightbox</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_nature.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_snow.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Snow">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<h2 style="text-align:center">Videos</h2>
 <div id="videos">
    <a data="uT6YOI6JcRs"></a>
    <a data="B9FzVhw8_bY"></a>
    <a data="d0K436vUM4w"></a>
    <a data="PhbWIFDqQfk"></a>
 </div>

 <div id="overlay">
    <div class="modal">
       <div id="close">X</div>
       <div id="loader"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I don't get errors. I wanted to be able to click to the images separated from the videos and vice-versa. If you delete the css from  VIDEÓ  to  VIDEÓ VÉGE  You can see that the image gallery is working. And if you delete the css from  VIDEÓ VÉGE  to the bottom of the style you can see that the video page is working too.

I tried to modify the z-indexes for both of the css codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the problem was that i used two of the same .modal in the css. I renamed the video's css modal to modale in both the css and in the html and everything is working. Thank you all!